# Execute Python script with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, node.js

I am trying to execute Python Script when I click on HTML button. Both files are on a Node.js Server. When I press the button I get this message in the browser console:

```
app.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: runPython is not defined
```

I am not sure how to write my AJAX script to call the runPython() function on my Node web server file. Below is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js">       </script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="myButton">Run Python Script</button>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      success: function(data) {
         runPython();
      },
    });
});
```

webserver.js (node.js)

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let mimes = {
  '.htm': 'text/html',
  '.css': 'text/css',
  '.js': 'text/javascript'
}

//Have ajax call it to execute Python Script
function runPython(){
    let exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('python myscript.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
}

function fileAccess(filepath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.access(filepath, fs.F_OK, error => {
      if(!error) {
        resolve(filepath);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

function streamFile(filepath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

        fileStream.on('open', () => {
            resolve(fileStream);
        });

        fileStream.on('error', error => {
            reject(error);
        });
      });
}

function webserver(req, res) {
  // if the route requested is '/', then load 'index.htm' or else
  // load the requested file(s)

  let baseURI = url.parse(req.url);
  let filepath = __dirname + (baseURI.pathname === '/' ? '/index.htm' :  baseURI.pathname);
  let contentType = mimes[path.extname(filepath)];

  fileAccess(filepath)
    .then(streamFile)
    .then(fileStream => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': contentType});
      //res.end(content, 'utf-8');
      fileStream.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(error));
    });


}

http.createServer(webserver).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Webserver running on port 3000');
});
```

How should I write the AJAX code so that the function in webserver.js will run?

Answer (score 0):

The browser is loading the script at that url. This is treated as either data or text. Browsers don't generally run Python so Working As Intended.

Comment: There has to be a way for the Python script to run when I click a button. What do I have to change in my code for script to run?

Comment: @user3062459 It could maybe run on the server side, if everything is setup right. You'd need to setup a handler that'll do the execution of the python when the right url is requested. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html. A more wrapped up way would be to install and use something like: https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell which is slightly different in style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an ajax request to the server that will run some code that will invoke your python script. You're missing the middle part of that process, and simply requesting the contents of `myscript.py` as text.

Something like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/invoke-script"
    });
});
```

I am not familiar with Node, but I imagine you have some sort of controller and the ability to execute commands (maybe using https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-sync). In that controller you then invoke your python script and do what you need with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this script like an executable. If your URL points to some *.exe file, clicking on the URL tells the web browser to download the resource. The same happens to Python script.
If you want to run some python code, try to handle HTTP request instead with simple HTTP server. This is the most common way to execute some actions on HTTP request. Check documentation for [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) and [BaseHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#module-BaseHTTPServer). 
[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer) and [here](http://www.acmesystems.it/python_httpd) you can find some code snippet for simple server implementation.